# Large donate button - too big

Tags: wordpress

I created a donate button and copied the exact code as provided, yet it is visually HUGE on my website. http://naomihattaway.com/about/mias-mission/

How do I get it down to a normal size?

Comment: Post the code you have for the image. I think a style class is changing the values of the image.

Answer (score 0):

In CSS i find this code when inspecting your donation button/image.

```
media="all"
input, select, textarea {
background-color: #fff;
border: 1px solid #ddd;
border-radius: 5px;
color: #333;
font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
font-size: 16px;
font-size: 1.6rem;
font-weight: 300;
padding: 10px;
padding: 1rem;
width: 100%;
}
```

By removing the "width:100%" the Button/image was normal sized then. Try this out and tell me if it helps.

Regards, Mike